# Why doesn't NotImplemented raise a TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators

Suppose I define a class `A` and I don't want anyone to write an inequality of that class without getting away.

```
class A():
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented
print(A() != A())
```

But this prints out `True` and doesn't raise a `TypeError` although I have deliberately "turned off" the `!=` operator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you return `NotImplemented` you indicate that you do not *know* if `__ne__` should return `True` or `False`.

Normally, Python will then swap the operands; if `a != b` results in `NotImplemented`, it'll try `b != a` instead. That'll fail here too, since you use the same type on both sides of the operator. For the `!=` operator, Python will then fall back to comparing their memory addresses, and these are not the same (two separate instances), so False is returned.

See the [`do_richcompare` C function for details](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e456da396ad9/Objects/object.c#l540).

You'll have to raise `TypeError()` manually if that is your expected outcome.

Comment: The simplicity of the 3.x rich comparison implementation is a welcome relief. In 2.x instead of calling `__ne__` twice, Python calls it 6 times (twice when `slot_tp_richcompare` is called by `PyObject_RichCompare`, then 4 more times when `try_rich_compare` tries in normal and swapped order). Finally it gets to the pointer comparison in `default_3way_compare`, complicated by having to cast to `uintptr_t` to support ordering.

Comment: Yeah, I was quite relieved to see the `python-3.x` tag on this question. Having to go into detail on how this all works in python 2 would have lead to a *slightly* longer answer. However, I count only *4* calls to `__ne__` for `A() != A()`, in the order LR, RL, RL, LR (for the left-hand and right-hand instances).

Answer (score -2):

It gives you True because you are **returning** an exception, an not **raising** it. This means that you are returning a non-Null object (the exception) as result of the test. Non-Null objects are evaluated as True unless otherwise specified.
Remember that the exception is a normal object until you raise it.

so you should have a method looking like this:

```
class A():
    def __ne__(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: No, it is *not* an exception. Read the documentation for [`__ne__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__); it is a singleton for just this purpose.

Comment: True, I was thinking about the exception. Don't get me wrong, but the documentation is flawed in this sense, as the bool() of NotImplemented return True, and doesn't give any kind a meaningful error. So, the correct procedure is to raise an exception, as least in the intention of the OP (as far as I can understand it)

Comment: No, `NotImplemented` is a very useful sentinel value (that is, a value to indicate that there is no implementation for something).

Comment: `NotImplemented` is a special singleton used for this kind of context. The Python comparison code tests for it specifically. I feel a dedicated exception would perhaps have been a better choice (such as `StopIteration`) but this is a holdover from the very early days of Python, I guess. However, there are probably edge cases where an exception is not the appropriate response. There are more uses of `NotImplemented` (and the C API equivalent `Py_NotImplemented`), in numeric coercion, for example.

Comment: If this answer is wrong, maybe you could edit or delete that?